# How to see which thread is going berserk in remote .NET application without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, debugging, windows-7, .net-4.0, process

I need to know which thread of an .NET application is going berserk. It consumes almost the complete CPU time.

The problem:

- The application is running on a remote PC
- My only access to the machine is via RDP
- There is no Visual Studio available at the customer's site
- So I'm not able to connect via Remote Debugging
- However, I would be able to copy some files to the machine and start tools there

My question:

- Is there a possibility to "see" (with standard tools or tools that I can just copy to the machine)

  - Which thread is consuming all the CPU time
  - What methods are called by this thread?

On "other operation systems" I can create a live call stack or initiate a dump in order to see if some thread is in an endless loop.
Is there such a possibility with Windows 7 & .NET?

Environment:

- Windows 7 (x86)
- .NET 4.0

Best regards and thanks

Seven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.
If the process is a x86 process running on a x86 OS or a x64 on a x64 OS, you only need the [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

1. Open the properties of the rogue application
2. Switch to the "Threads" tab
3. Sort by "CPU"
4. Select the thread with the high CPU usage and click "Stack". You should now see the managed stack of that thread. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/26/new-net-diagnostic-info-added-to-process-explorer.aspx) for more info.

---

If the process is x86 on a x64 OS, it will be a bit more involved. Please comment, if you need this info.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for. You made my day. Currently I do not need the info how to analyze 32bit apps on 64bit OSs. However, I could imaging that other people dropping at this post would be glad to get a hint to that.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Sam's standalone CPU analyzer](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application), which profiles the CPU to see what it is doing, generating a text file. The code for this was [released as OSS yesterday](https://github.com/SamSaffron/cpu-analyzer), if you have any concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Seems to be an interesting tool. I added it to my Tools directory. Maybe I could need it in the future. But for not the latest version of Process Explorer did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need visual studio installed to use the remote debugger as it is available as a standalone tool. You can either:

- Ask to have the firewall exception made to allow use of the remote debugger 'normally'
- Use something like PuTTy+freeSSHd to set up a reverse-tunnel between the remote machine and yours, and then use the remote debugger over the tunnel.

You could also use process explorer to see which thread is eating all the CPU time, but that'll just give you a relatively unhelpful thread handle instead of telling you much of any use.

The other thing you could do is convert the physical machine to a VM image, and boot that VM image locally to test.

Comment: To punch some holes into the firewall or using SSH's reverse tunneling was my first approach, too. But it proofed that I'm quite limited concerning network magic in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (already-installed) `perfmon.exe` tool to monitor the CPU utilization of each thread.

You might also want your application to create a log file, which associates some kind of thread name with each thread which you create, so that you know which thread is which.

Comment: I also look into that (accessing it via system task manager), but I could not figure out how to see single threads in there.